# Running Ceph Pacific in a Public Internet?

Tags: ceph

I am a little bit confused about the right setup of a ceph cluster running in the Internet. My goal is to access the ceph cluster from different Kubernetes Clusters.

My ceph nodes have public Internet IPs and also a private network 10.0.0.0/16

The /etc/hosts looks something like this:

```
127.0.1.1 node1.foo.com node1
127.0.0.1 localhost

#10.0.0.2        node1 
10.0.0.3        node2
10.0.0.4        node3
#23.aa.bb.cc    node1.foo.com
23.dd.ee.ff node2.foo.com
23.gg.hh.ii node3.foo.com
```

After boostraping my Ceph Cluster I set the cluster network :

```
$ sudo ceph config set mon cluster_network 10.0.0.0/16
```

And I set no Public Network so it defaults ot 0.0.0.0 (I guess)

Adding a new monitor node I provide the nodes public IP like this:

```
$ sudo ceph orch host add node2
$ sudo ceph orch daemon add mon node2:23.dd.ee.ff
```

Does this kind of network setup make sense? My cluster works and I can access it form my Kubernetes networks. And of course I also setup firewall rules to avoid trafic from unknown hosts.

My Ceph Pacific Cluster only logs some strange INFO log messages like this:

```
[INF]Filtered out host node3: does not belong to mon public_network ()
[INF]Filtered out host node2: does not belong to mon public_network ()
[INF]Filtered out host node1: does not belong to mon public_network ()
```

What does this message tell me? And how can I (if so) correct my Network setup?

Comment: This is not a secure way to run Ceph. The distinction between the public network and the cluster network separates components who expect to be in a trusted environment from those that don't have to be.

Comment: for your use case specifically, multiple k8s clusters located at separate locations connected by insecure networks, you can use a VPN to connect the k8s cluster to its Ceph storage.

Comment: But I do use a private netowork for OSD communication like replication. Why should it be insecure to access a ceph monitor via internet? I use a firewall rule to trust only my own kubernetes nodes.

Comment: the msgr protocol (what Ceph nodes speak to each other and to native clients) is not encrypted by default. You need to change that configuration if you intend to access storage from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are missing the `public network` setting, guess from your log: `does not belong to mon public_network`.

Try to set the `public network`, I can't figure out what's the default setting. But if you set `public network` only, it will set the `cluster network` assigned by `public network`.

Check from **[ceph network configuration reference](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/configuration/network-config-ref/#network-configuration-reference)**:

> Unless you specify a cluster network, Ceph assumes a single “public” network. Ceph functions just fine with a public network only, but you may see significant performance improvement with a second “cluster” network in a large cluster.

One more thing, in our cluster, we usually comment the line contain `127.0.1.1` for prevent some unknown network issue. And you should comment out this line `#10.0.0.2        node1` for resolve `node1` hostname.

Comment: I figured out that the reason was that I did not disable the automatic mon scheduling with `ceph orch apply mon --unmanaged`. This seems to have caused the log message

Answer (score 0):

A future update regarding what I believed you were asking in your title and first line:

**Title**: Running Ceph Pacific in a Public Internet?

**Context**: I am a little bit confused about the right setup of a ceph cluster running in the Internet. My goal is to access the ceph cluster from different Kubernetes Clusters.

My assumption was that you wanted this to be a secure setup being as it is on the internet. One of the comments mentions the use of a VPN and another states that CEPH msgr protocol on the storage network is unencrypted. Let's look at those two points:

**VPNs** - A virtual private network when powered by a high-cpu with a modern algorithm could work. The problem is that it adds another encapsulation network which ultimately will add latency and limit throughput. This is more appropriate for a client-server model between K8s applications and end users, not infrastructure.

**CEPH Messenger V2** - As stated in RedHat's release of Red Hat Ceph Storage 4:

> you can enable encryption for all Ceph traffic over the network with
> the introduction of the messenger version 2 protocol. The secure mode
> setting for messenger v2 encrypts communication between Ceph daemons
> and Ceph clients, giving you end-to-end encryption. [1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ceph_storage/4/html/data_security_and_hardening_guide/assembly-encryption-and-key-management)

What this means is, if you use Messenger V2 with *secure* mode, you could send the traffic over the internet with allow-lists and you'd be protected from Man-in-the-Middle attacks and other analysis. This is likely faster and better than encapsulation from another system that will add latency and cost you money to run.

Final word - Ceph Messenger V2 has been available since 2019 on CEPH Nautilus, so Pacific would also have it even at the time of asking. :)